# Xdebug VSCode ignore breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am using VSCode and Docker. After some research I realized these steps:

1. Install and config Xdebug on Docker ( also Xdebug log file )
2. Install Xdebug Extension for VSCode
3. Modify config in launch.json

Now if I open the simple "test.php" script on browser the debuger dont break on my break point, beside this I set the flag break on start up and these was also ignored. Have someone a hint for me?

My launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "/Users/MYUSERNAME/calc/"
              },
              "log": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Xdebug.log

```
[7] Log opened at 2019-03-15 16:32:32
[7] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[7] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[7] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[7] I: Remote address found, connecting to MYIP:9000.
[7] I: Connected to client. :-)
[7] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/web/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.0.27" protocol_version="1.0" appid="7" idekey="www-data"><engine version="2.7.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2019 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
[7]
[7] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>
[7]
[7] Log closed at 2019-03-15 16:32:33
```

Launch reponse form vscode

```
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true }
```

Port 9000 used by php-fpm now I use port 9001 , but the xdebug log show not successfull connection to client

```
[7] Log opened at 2019-03-15 17:26:20
[7] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[7] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[7] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[7] I: Remote address found, connecting to MYIP:9001.
[7] W: Creating socket for 'MYIP:9001', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[7] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
[7] Log closed at 2019-03-15 17:26:20
[7]
```

Also I changed the port in launch.json in vscode.
By the way I installed everything on a mac.

---

Now I solve my issue. I disable "remote_connect_back" and set my local ip to "remote_host". Now it works.

Comment: Change Xdebug port to some another port (e.g. `9001`) and try again. Right now you might be connecting to php-fpm (or some another service) that uses 9000 port by default. You may check using `netstat` (or whatever you have on your OS) to see who listens on that port.

Comment: @lazyone thank you now I change my port, but it cant connect to client now

Comment: Hi @Akif You should answer your own question with the solution you stated at the end of your post. Then mark your answer as the accepted answer. That way people like me know instantly that your problem is resolved and what the solution is ;) Thank you in advance